# Problem in dkms installation

Tags: 14.04, dkms

I'm terrible with Ubuntu, so I apologize of this is a terrible question to ask. However...while combating a wireless driver issue, I'm running the command to depackage the debian file by typing out

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

That's all well and good and the command goes through however I run into the error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuratino of bcmwl-kernel-source:
 bcmwl-kernel-source depends on dkms; however;
  Package dkms is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I'm sure the "Package dkms is not installed" is the highlight and central element to my current problem, however I put the whole error block there in the event I wasn't looking at it properly.

This is 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 and I'd appreciate any help with installing / finding the dkms package and getting it on my laptop here.

I'm currently on a Windows Machine without the capabilities of apt-get or anything like that, so if I could put it on a flash and be directed where to put it / where to install it on the laptop I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: you can search & download packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com/